# Evaluate: $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{2+\cos(x)}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this integral by using complex analysis, but don't know clearly what to do next. Here is my approach:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(x)}{2+\cos(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(z)}{2+\cos(z)}dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(e^{ix})}{2+\cos(e^{ix})}dx$$

Comment: If you don’t need complex analysis you can make a sub for $u = \tan(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: That's a good way to solve it but I need to use complex analysis.

Comment: are you taking a class in complex analysis or just entertaining it on your own? either way, it looks like you need to at least read your textbook and digest the examples. Or alternatively, there are literally dozens of examples on this website.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3072547/42969.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Residue theorem to the function $ f:z\mapsto\frac{1}{z^{2}+4z+1} $ on the unit cercle : $$ 2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(f,\sqrt{3}-2\right)=\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z} $$

$ \bullet \ \textrm{Res}\left(f,\sqrt{3}-2\right)=\lim\limits_{z\to \sqrt{3}-2}{\left(z+2-\sqrt{3}\right)f\left(z\right)}=\lim\limits_{z\to \sqrt{3}-2}{\frac{1}{z+2+\sqrt{3}}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} $

$ \bullet\ \textrm{Substituting }\small\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}z&=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}\\ \mathrm{d}z&=\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x}\,\mathrm{d}x\end{aligned}\right.\textrm{, we get that : }\oint_{\left|z\right|=1}{f\left(z\right)\mathrm{d}z}=\frac{\mathrm{i}}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+\cos{x}}} $

Thus : $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+\cos{x}}}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}} $$

Hence : $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos{x}}{2+\cos{x}}\,\mathrm{d}x}=2\pi-2\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{2+\cos{x}}}=2\pi-\frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{3}} $$